# Import select2 with parcel.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, parceljs

Pardon my lack of knowledge as I'm very new to web development.

I'm trying to bundle up all 3rd party packages, which includes `select2` among others.
The bundle works for the other packages like jquery, bootstrap, popper etc, but `select2` is not initialized or something. Perhaps some loading order issue?

Calling `$('select').select2()` results in uncaught type error.
Loading it separately via cdn or manual download works, so it seems parcel is not doing something right?

This is pretty much a very "boilerplatey" setup, so it's easy to replicate, but this is what I'm currently trying it on:

```
File structure:
- node_modules
- index.html
- .sassrc       # sass configuration
- assets/       # front end assets root
  - scss/       # Place for all styles
    - site.scss
  - js/         # Place for all scripts
    - site.js
  - bundle.js   # Entry point for output bundle
```

```js
// bundle.js
import './scss/site.scss';
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
import 'bootstrap';
import 'select2';
```

```css
/* site.css */
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "select2/dist/css/select2";
@import "@ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme/dist/select2-bootstrap4";
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="wwwroot/dist/bundle.css">
  <script src="wwwroot/dist/bundle.js"></script>
</head>
```

And lastly

```
// package.js to show dependencies and the build script
{
  "name": "SideNav",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "parcel build assets/bundle.js --out-dir wwwroot/dist/"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme": "^1.3.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "select2": "^4.0.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.4",
    "sass": "^1.32.5"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance to everyone helping out.

Answer (score 1):

For me select2 worked in this way:

```
import $ from "jquery";
import select2 from "select2";

select2($);
window.$ = $;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will work for you:

```js
import $ from "jquery";
import select2 from "select2";
import 'select2/dist/css/select2.min.css';

select2($);


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.chosen').select2();
});
```

Notice that the .css is important in order to get the styling of select2

The `select2($);` call effectively initializes the select2 plugin with the jQuery instance, making the select2 function available as a method on the jQuery object.